# Woocommerce Underscore is added to some product URLs

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Got an unusual problem that started recently and wonder if anyone has any ideas why it's happening and how to stop it.

Some of my products are getting an underscore added to the url when selected which, naturally, results in a 404 error. It's consistent - either an underscore gets added or it doesn't. It doesn't seem to be related to the GUID or the post_name in the wp_posts table.  It also doesn't matter if you call it using the URL or the post ID so the following:-

```
Bad  index.php?page_id=1075707  the-john-rutter-christmas-piano-album-2 https://website-name.com/product/the-john-rutter-christmas-piano-album-2/
Good index.php?page_id=1087442  the-john-rutter-piano-album             https://website-name.com/product/the-john-rutter-piano-album/
Bad  index.php?page_id=1159681  parable-for-harpsichord                 https://website-name.com/product/parable-for-harpsichord/
Good index.php?page_id=1159684  jesu-meine-freude-2                     https://website-name.com/product/jesu-meine-freude-2/
```

Bad here meaning that the URL appears with an underscore such as

```
https://website-name.com/product/parable-for-harpsichord_/
```

I've also tried this with every single plugin, except WooCommerce, de-activated and with my functions.php disabled.  No difference.

I've tried using the URLs as given above, C&P or typed in manually and by directly referencing the post ID (as shown).

This has only recently started and I'm at a bit of a loss here. I don't know how widespread this problem is either since I've over 120,000 products and can't check them all by hand. Fortunately, this isn't live yet.

Any suggestions or ideas here would help me.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a hidden character at the end of the post_name field. Deleting and recreating the field got rid of the problem.